# Replace a string using regex;

Tags: c#, regex

I have a xml file with some info. I need to replace some words from that with another word.

In the below example, I need to remove the "go" keyword with "C#":

> Something like I'm going to have section on go language

For that I have wrote a regex like:

```
        string reg = "[^a-zA-Z09]go[^a-zA-Z09]";
        var r = new Regex(reg);
        r.Replace("Something like I'm going to have section on go language", "C#");
        //The expected result is Something like I'm going to have section on C# language
```

But the issue is, it's replacing with the space around the " go ".
If I use string replace function, it will remove go from going as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `\b` in your regular expression: this is used for matching **word boundaries**.

```
string reg = @"\bgo\b";
```

Test that [here](http://regexr.com/45gtk).